# CentOS Kickstart url command: Can I make it choose a mirror for me?

Tags: centos, kickstart

Whenever I install [RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux), I use a [Kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/index) file. I want to take the Kickstart file that I use with RHEL, and make a version of it that works with [CentOS](https://centos.org/).

My Kickstart file uses [`cmdline`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#cmdline_kickstart-commands-for-installation-program-configuration-and-flow-control) to make sure that the installation is fully automatic. [RHEL’s Kickstart reference says](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#cdrom_kickstart-commands-for-installation-program-configuration-and-flow-control)

> To actually run the installation, you must specify one of `cdrom`, `harddrive`, `hmc`, `nfs`, `liveimg`, `ostreesetup`, `rhsm`, or `url` unless the `inst.repo` option is specified on the kernel command line.

I don’t really care where the packages come from. I just want the installation to be as automatic as possible. I use [`rhsm`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#rhsm_kickstart-commands-for-installation-program-configuration-and-flow-control) on my RHEL systems so that I don’t have to bother registering the system afterwards.

I’m assuming that `rhsm` isn’t available in CentOS, so I need to use something else. I can’t use [`cdrom`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#cdrom_kickstart-commands-for-installation-program-configuration-and-flow-control) because I’m booting the installer from USB, and none of my systems have CD drives anymore. [`url`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/kickstart-commands-and-options-reference_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#url_kickstart-commands-for-installation-program-configuration-and-flow-control) seems close to what I want, but I don’t know what mirror to choose. Is there anyway to say “choose a mirror, I don’t really care which one”?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to say “choose a mirror, I don’t really care which one”?

Yes.

### CentOS Stream

```
url --metalink=https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-$releasever-stream&arch=$basearch&protocol=https
```

### CentOS Linux

```
url --mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?repo=os&release=$releasever&arch=$basearch
```